# Sections of a vector bundle taking values in a gerbe

Tags: homological-algebra, gerbes

We can make sense of sections of a vector bundle taking values in a line bundle; an oversimplified answer might be sections of the vector bundle tensored with the line bundle. However, I can't see the same idea working for a gerbe. Is there a notion of sections of vector bundles taking values in a gerbe (say, an n-gerbe)? If not is there a way around it?

Comment: Why would you expect such a thing to exist, and what properties do you want it to have? The question is currently too vague to answer.